# Seg fault error when copying an existing pointer

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is a linked list implementation for a class project, and it's all working except for this function. I have narrowed down the location of the seg-fault to the indicated line (wrapped in 'std::cout...' statments.

```cpp
// Purpose: removes a section of a lists
// Parameters:    start pointer to the begining of the section to remove.
//                end pointer to the end of the section to remove.
// Preconditions: start and end are pointers to nodes in this list.
//                start precedes end in this list.
// Postconditions: elements between start and end (inclusive) are removed
//                 from the list.
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clip(LLNode<T>* start, LLNode<T>* stop)
{
  if(m_size > 2)
  {
    LLNode<T>* walker = m_head;
    LLNode<T>* hold;
    LLNode<T>* deleter;
    while(walker != start)
    {
      hold = walker;
      walker = walker -> m_next;
    }
    int i;
    //TODO: seg-fault here
    if(stop == NULL)
    {
      hold -> m_next = NULL;
    }
    else if(stop -> m_next == NULL)
    {
      hold -> m_next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "error on next line\n";
      hold -> m_next = stop -> m_next;
      std::cout << "oh... i guess it's fixed...\n";
    }
    if(hold -> m_next == NULL)
    {
      m_back = hold;
    }
    stop -> m_next = NULL;
    walker = start;
    while(walker != NULL && walker -> m_next != NULL)
    {
      hold = walker;
      walker = walker -> m_next;
      delete deleter;
      deleter = hold;
      i++;
    }
    delete walker;
    delete deleter;
    m_size -= i;
  }
  else
  {
    clear();
  }
}
```

The output comes out like this:

> error on next line
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't handle the case when `start` is equal to head (`hold` is yet uninitialised then!).

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't caught that! The problem persists with the start and end both in the middle of the list though. :/

EDIT: Even though my test didn't use the head as the start, that fixed it. I'll post the updated code as a solution! Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to handle `stop->m_next` being `nullptr` separately, that's covered by following else as well. And you should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: `while(walker != start)` -> you don't need `walker = start;` before deleting (but not an error either...).

Comment: You can delete much simpler: `while(walker) { hold = walker; walker = walker->m_next; delete hold; ++i; } /*no deletes afterwards*/ `

Comment: `if(m_size >/*!*/ 2) { } else { clear(); }` – and if `stop` is direct successor of `start` or start is second element? You wouldn't want to remove both elements then...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had overlooked the edge case of 'start' being equal to the head.

This is the fully fixed code:

```cpp
// Purpose: removes a section of a lists
// Parameters:    start pointer to the begining of the section to remove.
//                end pointer to the end of the section to remove.
// Preconditions: start and end are pointers to nodes in this list.
//                start precedes end in this list.
// Postconditions: elements between start and end (inclusive) are removed
//                 from the list.
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clip(LLNode<T>* start, LLNode<T>* stop)
{
  LLNode<T>* walker = m_head;
  LLNode<T>* deleter;
  LLNode<T>* lastNodeOnFront;
  if(m_head == start)
  {
    lastNodeOnFront = m_head;
  }
  while(walker != start)
  {
    lastNodeOnFront = walker;
    walker = walker -> m_next;
  }
  std::cout << *this;
  if(stop == m_back || stop == NULL)
  {
    lastNodeOnFront -> m_next = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    lastNodeOnFront -> m_next = stop -> m_next;
  }
  std::cout << "before delete\n" << *this;
  walker = start;
  while(walker != lastNodeOnFront -> m_next)
  {
    deleter = walker;
    walker = walker -> m_next;
    delete deleter;
    m_size--;
  }
  return;
}
```

Thanks to Aconcagua for the help!